# Is it possible to include different versions of js files into html file in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Suppose i have different versions of jquery.min.js and other version .If i want to include both in html script tag,may be there is a conflict over those files which have to choose.So can we overcome that conflict

Comment: Why would you want to include both, that's the real question

Comment: @Eric sometimes you have to because plugins depend on specific versions.

Comment: If i have any usage of both the files of different versions.One version supports one thing another have advanced.So how to to use both

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: try using `jQuery.noConflict()` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple versions of jQuery can be included by using [`noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). For instance, if you wanted to include the 1.x and 2.x versions on the same page, you could reference each by supplying an alias:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>var jq1x = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script>
  // $ == jQuery 2.x
  $('#foo').on('click',function(){
    // binding using 2.x
  });
</script>
<script>
  (function($){
    // $ == jQuery 1.x
    $('#bar').on('click',function(){
      // binding using 1.x
    });
  })(jq1x);
</script>
```